# Select template menu for custom post types?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a couple of custom post types in wordpress, and have set hierarchical to true so it behaves as a page.

The problem is, templates selection isn't available. I've applied [this hack](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-template-dropdown-for-post-types-other-than-page) to get the menu to appear:

> there is a file meta-boxes.php within
>   wp-admin\includes of the wordpress
>   installation.. line 547 of the file,
>   which is the function
>   page_attributes_meta_box() just add
>   the check for your particular post
>   type name to be able to display the
>   template pages drop down.
>
> ```
> if ( ('page' == $post->post_type  || 'yourcustomposttype' == $post->post_type) && 0 != count( get_page_templates() ) ) {
>         $template = !empty($post->page_template) ? $post->page_template : false;
>         ?>
> ```

This successfully makes the menu appear, but the data won't save. The "parent" section saves but the "template" doesn't.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this plugin and it was ok for posts, try it :)

https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/

Comment: Cheers, I've already got that plugin running and unless I'm missing something it doesn't do what I need for custom post types

Comment: Yes, but I think it should be possible to have it do what you want with some little modifications.

Comment: I ended up just scrapping custom post types in the end, but I will mark this as the answer as it is the (only!) best one here.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is built into core since 4.7. Enable the functionality inside the applicate custom template. For example, if you have a template called "Promotions" and you want to apply it to your CPT "usa, uk, au"

```
<?php 
  /* 
    Template Name: Promotions
    Template Post Type: page, usa, uk, au
  */

get_header(); ?>
```

[WordPress 4.7 Brings Custom Page Template Functionality to All Post Types](https://wptavern.com/wordpress-4-7-brings-custom-page-template-functionality-to-all-post-types)

Comment: This is the best answer. No plugin required, just works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this question looking for the same functionality. I know this is a little late but I think I found the solution. By looking into the readme file with the plugin you can add this to your functions.php for the functionality you're looking for.

```
/**
 * Hooks the WP cpt_post_types filter 
 *
 * @param array $post_types An array of post type names that the templates be used by
 * @return array The array of post type names that the templates be used by
 **/
function my_cpt_post_types( $post_types ) {
    $post_types[] = 'movie';
    $post_types[] = 'actor';
    return $post_types;
}
add_filter( 'cpt_post_types', 'my_cpt_post_types' );
```